# Can you use multiple rigs in Blender

Tags: animation

I'm new to blender, and am trying to make a Minecraft animation. I can get a single character in, but don't know how to have multiple rigs in a single animation.

How do you have multiple characters?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's fairly simple, really. If you're using a good rig, it should be in a group and you can import it easily.

First, find whatever file you plan on animating with (I'm using a blank one):
[image: yee]

Then, go to File>Append...
[image: yee]

Find the rig you want add to your animation...
[image: yee]

Open it and select "Group..."
[image: yee]

Select the group...
[image: yee]

There it is! The rig is there. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> to get rid of that pesky green outline.
[image: yee]

Now, if the rig creator hasn't already put it in a group, then it's up to you to do that, which is fortunately quite trivial.

First, open the original rig file and select everything that's a part of the rig.
[image: yee]

Then, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> to put everything you've selected into a single group.
[image: yee]

Now, repeat to import the rig!

Optional step: press F6 to bring up the Action Properties panel. You can then specify a name for the group, which is especially useful if there are multiple rigs in one file.
[image: yee]

Answer (score 4):

You can have as many rigs as you like it is pretty much the same as adding objects. You might be confused when you started your animation in the *Timeline*. You will only see the keyframes of the selected object.

I would recommend to learn about [*Actions*](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Animation/Editors/DopeSheet/Action) ( parts of an animation like: walk, jump etc.) and the [NLA-editor](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Animation/Editors/NLA) this allows you to reuse already created actions to assemble an animation from actions.

Answer (score 2):

**Yes**, as you said, you havemultiple rigs!

you must have 2 characters , and the only way to do this is by making separate animations for each rig ( Make each rig have its own couple of animations like shown in the video ) . Then , you select the animation for both rigs that correspond to each other , so when you render it will play the animation that you want to play

if that makes sense

---

I made this video , And it might come in handy for exactly what you need!

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E-8K1yG6uyE&list=UU28bfUuaupS-1mzytSUmlrw